# Jenkins node terminated after changing password for Jenkins user

Tags: jenkins

I connected Mac machine as a node for jenkins. It was connected fine, but then I reset password for Jenkins user on the Mac machine and after that node status displayed terminated all the time. Could anyone advice how to fix this? Thanks! 
Here's error it displayed on the node page:

````
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer.onReadClosed(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:209)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.onRecvClosed(ApplicationLayer.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.onRecvClosed(ProtocolStack.java:816)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.FilterLayer.onRecvClosed(FilterLayer.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.onRecvClosed(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.switchToNoSecure(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:283)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processWrite(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.processQueuedWrites(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:248)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:200)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.SSLEngineFilterLayer.doCloseSend(SSLEngineFilterLayer.java:213)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ProtocolStack$Ptr.doCloseSend(ProtocolStack.java:784)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.ApplicationLayer.doCloseWrite(ApplicationLayer.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.ChannelApplicationLayer$ByteBufferCommandTransport.closeWrite(ChannelApplicationLayer.java:314)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1452)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1405)
    at jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.afterChannel(DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver.java:173)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState$4.invoke(JnlpConnectionState.java:421)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fire(JnlpConnectionState.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpConnectionState.fireAfterChannel(JnlpConnectionState.java:418)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol4Handler$Handler$1.run(JnlpProtocol4Handler.java:334)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: Why not just delete the slave and then reattach it as a new slave?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I tried that and problem persist.